# Хранение наследников в массиве типа базового класса

Tags: c++, наследование

Товарищи, подскажите, пожалуйста, одну вещь.

Необходимо создать некоторое количество экземпляров нескольких классов, которые являются дочерними от одного суперкласса. Я догадываюсь, что так делать нельзя:

```
SuperClass ptrSuper[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i / 2)
        ptrSuper[i] = new Naslednik1(....);
    else
        ptrSuper[i] = new Naslednik2(....);
};
```

Как здесь можно поступить?

Comment: Видимо, вы имели ввиду `SuperClass* ptrSuper[100];`

Comment: Солидарен с пользователем Котик_хочет_кушать - здесь нужно использовать указатель. Также возможно использовать не стандартный массив, а std::vector. У него есть определенные преимущества, но желательно, чтобы классы удовлетворяли определенным условиям, иначе можно поом сильно удивиться.

Answer (score 6):

Это не ответ на ваш вопрос, т.к на него уже ответили, но просто некоторая информация для размышления.

*Если бы вариант вашего кода выглядел следующим образом, то эта запись также возможна, однако, в этом случае будет происходит нежелательное явление под названием* **срезка** / **slicing :**

```
SuperClass ptrSuper[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 2)
        ptrSuper[i] = Naslednik1(....);
    else
        ptrSuper[i] = Naslednik2(....);
};
```

Суть явления срезки заключается в том, что на деле вместо пересвязывания указателей *(а это то, чего мы хотели на самом деле)* происходит неочевидное полное копирование объектов, причем в данном случае копирование **только части `SuperClass`.**

Т.е во всех созданных объектах лишняя информация, которая составляет "суть" классов `Naslednik1`, `Naslednik2`, будет безвозвратно утеряна.

---

Другие примеры срезки можно изучить [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, как я понял у вас есть иерарархия классов. Например SuperClass и от него наследуется два класса Derived1 и Derived2:

```
class SuperClass
{
...
};
class Derived1 : public SuperClass
{
};
class Derived2 : public SuperClass
{
};
```

и вам необходим некий контейнер, в котором вы хотите хранить объекты этих классов. Скажу сразу тут желательно использовать указатели... Почему? Есть замечательная книжка Скотта Мейерса, там как раз очень хорошо объясняется в одном из правил, что прозойдёт "срезка", впрочем http://hashcode.ru/users/751/mikillskegg уже писал про это тут.

дак вот, я бы хранил эти объекты так

```
std::vector< *SuperClass > OurContainer;
OurContainer.push_back( new Derived1 );
OurContainer.push_back( new Derived2 );
```

...
в конце не забываем удалять объекты их кучи, "пробагемся" по вектору с помощью итератора и удаляем каждый указатель.

Comment: Отмечу, что использование `Container<Object*>`, вообще говоря, не является хорошей идеей, т.к в тот момент, когда объект попадает в контейнер, становится непонятно, **на кого возлагается ответственность за его освобождение.** Ситуация становится еще более плачевной в случае, если этот контейнер каким-то образом доступен извне. *Решение - использование чего-либо в духе `Container<shared_ptr<Object> >`.*

Comment: согласен с Вами полностью, но! Я данный вопрос, возник у человека в процессе образования и использовать shared_ptr пока рано-то. Так что я привёл более простой пример.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (i%2)
   ptrSuper[i] = new Naslednik1(....);
else
   ptrSuper[i] = new Naslednik2(....);
```

в элементы с четными индексами (0,2 ... 98) попадут Naslednik1, а с нечетными (1 ... 99) Naslednik2

Это, если вы с описанием наследования ничего не напутали.

Answer (score 1):

Если указателю на базовый класс присвоить адрес производного класса, то не будет доступа к методам и переменным производного класса, которых нет в классе базовом. Так что лучше сделать два массива указателей на каждый производный класс, и спокойненько их заполнить с помощью new.

Answer (score 1):

Два момента:

1. Используйте `std::vector` вместо стандартного массива
2. Используйте `std::shared_ptr` вместо сырого указателя
3. Используйте фабричный метод, вместо размещения логики создания экземпляра нужного типа в месте помещения созданного экземпляра в вектор

Вот пример кода:

```
// Может быть пока и не нужно, но значительно проще, когда
// за процесс создания экземпляра отвечает отдельный метод.
// Так проще об этом думать, и развивать
std::shared_ptr<SuperClass> CreateSuperClass(int index)
{
  return index%2 ? std::make_shared(new Derived1) : std::make_shared(new Derived2);
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SuperClass>> mySuperclasses;
for(int n = 0; n < size; n++)
{
  mySuperClasses.push_back(CreateSuperClass(n));
}
```

Преимущества:

- Не нужно задумываться о процессе освобождения элементов вектора благодаря `std::shared_ptr`
- Процесс создания вынесен в отдельный метод, что упрощает чтение и позволяет изменять процесс создания не трогая дополнительные участки кода