# Ошибка при добавлении объектов разных классов в список - C++

Tags: c++, наследование, список, полиморфизм

Добрый день.

Задача:

1. Определить иерархию классов (в соответствии с вариантом).
2. Определить в классе статическую компоненту - указатель на начало связанного списка объектов и статическую функцию для просмотра списка.
3. Реализовать классы.
4. Написать демонстрационную программу, в которой создаются объекты различных классов и помещаются в список, после чего список просматривается.

main:

```
int main() {
Worker worker1 = Worker();
worker1.setFio((char *) "WorkerFIO");
worker1.setAge(143);

List test = List();
test.add(worker1);

printArr();

worker1.~Worker();
}
```

класс Staff (базовый, абстрактный)

```
class Staff {
public:
Staff() {}
virtual ~Staff() {}

virtual void calcSalary() = 0;

void setFio(char *fio) {
    ...
}
void setAge(int age) {
    ...
}

char* getFio() {
    ...
}
int getAge() {
    ...
}
protected:
/*some fields*/
};
```

Класс Worker (наследуется от Staff)

```
class Worker : public Staff {
public:
Worker() {}
~Worker() {}

void calcSalary() {
     ...
}
private:
/* some fields */
};
```

Список. В него должны добавляться объекты классов, наследованные от Staff. При этом производных от Staff классов будет несколько, они все должны добавляться в этот список.

```
struct staff {
Staff st;
staff *next;
};

static staff *begin;

static void printArr() {
staff *curr = begin;
while (curr != NULL) {
    std::cout<<curr->st.getFio()<<std::endl;
    curr = curr->next;
}
}

class List {
private:
public:
List() {
    begin = NULL;
}
List(Staff st) {
    begin = NULL;
    add(st);
}
~List() {}
void add(Staff st) {
    staff *s = new staff;
    s->st = st;
    if (begin == NULL) {
        begin = s;
    } else {
        staff *curr = begin;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = s;
    }
}
};
```

Суть проблемы:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.3.4\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build G:\Development\C++\Lab4\cmake-build-debug --target Lab4 -- -j 4
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Lab4.dir/main.cpp.obj
In file included from G:\Development\C++\Lab4\main.cpp:14:0:
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\List.h:12:11: error: cannot declare field 'staff::st' to be of abstract type 'Staff'
 Staff st;
       ^
In file included from G:\Development\C++\Lab4\main.cpp:13:0:
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\Staff.h:4:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Staff':
class Staff {
   ^
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\Staff.h:9:18: note:     virtual void Staff::calcSalary()
 virtual void calcSalary() = 0;
              ^
In file included from G:\Development\C++\Lab4\main.cpp:14:0:
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\List.h:32:16: error: cannot declare parameter 'st' to be of abstract type 'Staff'
 List(Staff st) {
            ^
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\List.h:37:20: error: cannot declare parameter 'st' to be of abstract type 'Staff'
 void add(Staff st) {
                ^
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\List.h: In constructor 'List::List(Staff)':
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\List.h:34:15: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Staff'
     add(st);
           ^
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
G:\Development\C++\Lab4\main.cpp:23:21: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Staff'
 test.add(worker1);
                 ^
```

В чем суть проблемы, я понял. Нельзя просто так взять и создать объект абстрактного класса (на то он и абстрактный). Вопрос следующий - как в список добавить объекты классов, производные от абстрактного класса. Производных классов будет несколько.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Хранение наследников в массиве типа базового класса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44986/%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор ругается, потому что вы поместили в структуру `staff` тело базового класса:

```
struct staff {
    Staff st;     // <=== 
    staff *next;
};
```

Соответственно, при создании экземпляра структуры `staff` будет создан и экземпляр класса `Staff`, а его поля будут храниться внутри этой структуры. Из-за этого мы не можем хранить в `st` производные классы (не хватит зарезервированного места).

Для решения вашей задачи **необходимо использовать указатели**:

- либо невладеющие с явными `new` и `delete`:

  ```
  struct staff {
      Staff *st;
      staff *next;
  };
  ```
- либо владеющие (если вы используете C++11):

  ```
  struct staff {
      std::unique_ptr<Staff> st;
      staff *next;
  };
  ```

Указателю абсолютно без разницы, сколько места занимают данные класса, поэтому он может адресовать любого потомка, реализующего виртуальные методы базового класса.

***P. S.*** Вообще компилятор ругается на невозможность порождения экземпляра класса `Staff` из-за наличия в нём чисто виртуальных методов. При этом классы-потомки компилятора не интересуют, так как поле может содержать **только** экземпляры `Staff`-а.

***P. P. S.*** Как правильно [заметил @Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647365/208074), в Си и C++, в отличие от Java, переменные хранятся по значению (то есть по месту объявления), пока явно не указано иного. Другими словами, любая переменная — это не ссылка, а собственно значение с предварительно выделенным под него местом неизменного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Перефразируя О. Бендера - Тяжкое наследие Java? :)

Не передают в С++ такие вещи по значению:

```
void add(Staff st);
```

Работать надо с указателями (или ссылками, что, в общем-то, одно и то же)...

```
struct staff {
    Staff st;
    staff *next;
};
```

Та же проблема - фактически здесь должен быть создан экземпляр абстрактного класса. Как?

Так что добавляйте, например, указатели.

P.S. Вы сами не путаетесь в `Staff` и `staff`?

P.P.S. Кстати,

```
Worker worker1 = Worker();
```

можно написать проще:

```
Worker worker1;
```

Comment: Да, вы угадали, во всем виновата Java =)

Comment: По вот этому: `Worker worker1 = Worker();` - очень уж характерная вещь...