# Хранение объектов разных типов

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть абстрактный класс "Organism". Его наследуют 2 классa: "Animals" и "Plants"

Как образом можно хранить объекты классов "Animals" и "Plants" в 1 массиве\векторе\чём-либо ещё

Comment: Каким угодно...  Если у этих классов нет каких-то специфических особенностей, то и в их хранении нет никаких специфических особенностей. Непонятно в чем тут проблема.

Comment: возможно, пригодится  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44986/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Так как речь идёт скорее всего о компьютерной игре, а класс Animals и Plants будут представлены как объекты управления, то лучше всего использовать фабрику паттернов, для создания самих объектов, а их указатели хранить в std::list или std::forward_list, так как скорость вставки и удаления( рождение, смерть) элемента будет константной.

Comment: `*Animal` и `*Plant` это разные типы. Вы предлагаете к `*void` их приводить? Это дико опасно, лучшие их в `any` хранить. Но это все равно не решает кучу проблем. Например никак не получиться сделать вызов `l[1].call()`, можно только `std::any_cast<Animal>(l[1]).call()`

Comment: Здесь же вопрос не в чем хранить, а как...

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

// Вначале объявим базовый класс
class Organism {
public:
  virtual string name() = 0;
  virtual ~Organism() = default;
};

// наследники

class Animal : public Organism
{
  public:
    string name() override { return "Animal"; }
};

class Plant: public Organism
{
  public:
    string name() override { return "Plant"; }
};



int main() {
    // так как на дворе 2018, то пишем на 11 стандарте и используем умные указатели
    vector<unique_ptr<Organism>> org;
    // и добавление без new
    org.push_back(make_unique<Plant>());
    org.push_back(make_unique<Animal>());
    // а вот здесь объязательно нужно const и &, так как unique_ptr
    for (const auto& o : org) {
        // name - виртуальная, поэтому никаких dynamic_cast
        cout << o->name() << endl;
    }
    // и память за нас компилятор освободит.
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно, в будущем, нужно будет unique_ptr заменить на shared_ptr.

Или это все таки школьная задача и преподаватель будет компилировать в turbo c++ 3?

Comment: интересно, а что же не так, что решили минус поставить? или сложное решение? (или может противники решения школьных заданий?)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Создадим массив и добавим в него одно животное и два растения:
std::vector<Organism*> mas;
mas.push_back(new Plant);
mas.push_back(new Animal);
mas.push_back(new Plant);

// Узнаем, то, что лежит ли в mas[1] это растение или животное:
if (dynamic_cast<Plant*>(mas[1]))
{
    std::cout << "this is Plant" << std::endl;
}
else if (dynamic_cast<Animal*>(mas[1]))
{
    std::cout << "this is Animal" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "this is unknown Organism" << std::endl;
}

// Удаление:
for (int i = 0; i < mas.size(); ++i)
{
    delete mas[i];
}
mas.clear();
// Если всё было сделано верно, и деструктор класса Organism был объявлен как виртуальный, то delete вызовет правильный деструктор и утечки памяти не будет
```

Comment: код не скомпилируется - удаление немного не правильно написано. либо используйте старый вид for, либо тело перепишите.

Comment: Исправил. Использовал старый вид for.